# Is there an Apache Velocity plugin for Netbeans 6.5 or higher?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, plugins, velocity

I'm looking for a plugin similar to the Eclipse plugins [Veloeclipse](http://propsorter.sourceforge.net/) or [Velocity Web Edit](http://velocitywebedit.sourceforge.net/) for NetBeans.

**Update:** I tried the [Velocity Editor Support](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=9155) plugin mentioned by [Kathy Van Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115432/kathy-van-stone) (thanks!), but it's not quite as robust as I had hoped. It doesn't support code folding, directive tag matching, or code completion, as far as I can tell.  It could be a compatibility issue with NetBeans 6.5, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=9155) for 6.1. Is that likely to work for you?  If not, you can ask the author about it.